# How do I clean out my /tmp directory upon reboot?

Tags: linux, files, reboot, tmp, delete

I’m using Amazon Linux.  Below is the uname info …

```
[davea@mymachine ~]$ uname -a
Linux sandbox.mydomain.com 4.4.18-35.99.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 27 22:37:49 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Even when I do a

```
sudo reboot now
```

The /tmp directory isn’t getting cleaned out.  I verify this by noting that the dates on the files are before the reboot.  How can I set things up so that when I reboot, the /tmp directory is cleaned out?

**Edit:** Per the request in the comment, below is the /etc/fstab file

```
#
LABEL=/     /           ext4    defaults,noatime  1   1
tmpfs       /dev/shm    tmpfs   defaults        0   0
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0   0
sysfs       /sys        sysfs   defaults        0   0
proc        /proc       proc    defaults        0   0
```

Comment: I imagine your expectation for the `/tmp` directory to be cleaned is because you're used to a `tmpfs` filesystem mounted on `tmp` from some other distro/configuration. It sounds like your `/tmp` directory is a partition on your hard drive instead. How about you post your `/etc/fstab`? You can easily change what get mounted on `/tmp` with it.

Comment: Done!  It is attached as an edit to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To introduce a 1GB /tmp that sits in tmpfs and therefore clears on boot, add this line to `/etc/fstab` and then reboot.

```
tmpfs   /tmp         tmpfs   nodev,nosuid,size=1G          0  0
```

More info on [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmpfs)